# worklight 6.2 native api adapter invocation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

In JavaScript my Worklight Client can pass arbitrary objects to an adapter:

```
var payload = { able: 3488, baker: "wibble"};

var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'xxx',
    procedure : 'xxx',
    parameters : [payload],
    compressResponse : false
};

var options = {
        onSuccess: onCallSuccess,
        onFailure: onCallFailure    
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

and the adapter can access the object

```
 function xxx(p1) {  
      return {'answer': p1.able};
 }
```

In the native APIs it seems that we are limited to primitive types:

> public void setParameters(java.lang.Object[] parameters)
>
> This method
> sets the request parameters. The order of the object in the array will
> be the order sending them to the adapter
>
> Parameters: Object -
> parameters An array of objects of primitive types ( String, Integer,
> Float, Boolean, Double). The order of the objects in the array is the
> order in which they are sent to the adapter.

Hence if my adapters are to be used by both JavaScript and Native clients they will need to accept any complex objects as JSON Strings. **Unless there is an alternative I'm missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a better alternative than simply stringifying the object as you have suggested. Are you using objects other than JSON in your native side? If so what is the structure of the object?